# Return value from OkHttpClient async request

Tags: java, android, okhttp

In my first android project i made an onClick event to call a function:

```
public void doSomething(View v) {
        String result = authenticate();
        [...]
}
```

This function calls the method:

```
private String authenticate() {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        [...]

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                [...]
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String responseString = response.body().string();

                    try {
                        JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
                        String responseObjectAccessToken = responseObject.getString("accesstoken");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

now i would like to return the **responseObjectAccessToken** to my **doSomething** function. A detailed explanation would be great since I am new to Java and Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion is to handle that async response through a callback which is passed as an argument to your `authenticate` method. Here I'm using Java 8 lambda for that one method interface.

```java
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  public interface AuthCallback {
    void onAuthResult(String token);
  }

  private String authenticate(AuthCallback callback) {
    // ...
    String responseObjectAccessToken = responseObject.getString("accesstoken");
    callback.onAuthResult(responseObjectAccessToken)
    // ...
  }

  public void doSomething(View v) {
    authenticate((token) -> {
      // do something with token
    });
  }

  // ...

}
```

As you can see that callback could be stored if you wanted to:

```java
// ...
AuthCallback cb = new AuthCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onAuthResult(String token) {
    // do something in the view/fragment/activity
  }
}

// then pass it as argument
```

or your class could implement this interface and pass itself into the method:

```java
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements AuthCallback {
  @Override
  public void onAuthResult(String token) {
    // do something
  }

  // ...

  public void doSomething(View v) {
    authenticate(MyActivity.this); // <-- pass itself
  }
}
```

One important point here is that networking happens on a separate thread, so if you want to have some UI changes after your API responds you could use a helper method [runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) to do changes on main ui thread instead:

```java
authenticate((token) -> {
  runOnUiThread(() -> {
    // do something with UI here
  })
});
```